# How to write inline files in a Makefile

Tags: python, makefile, response, inline

I've seen some shell scripts in which they pass a file by writing the contents of the file in the same shell script. For instance:

```
if [[ $uponly -eq 1 ]]; then
    mysql $tabular -h database1 -u usertrack -pabulafia usertrack << END                                                                                           

    select host from host_status where host like 'ld%' and status = 'up';                                                                                          

END
     exit 0
fi
```

I've been able to do something similar in which I do:

```
python << END
print 'hello world'
END
```

If the name of the script is say `myscript.sh` then I can run it by executing `sh myscript.sh`. and I obtain my desired output.

Question is, can we do something similar in a Makefile? I've been looking around and they all say that I have do something like:

```
target:
        python @<<
print 'hello world'
<<
```

But that doesn't work.

Here are the links where I've been looking:

http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm#Response%20Files

http://www.scribd.com/doc/2369245/Makefile-Memo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
define TMP_PYTHON_PROG
print 'hello'
print 'world'
endef

export TMP_PYTHON_PROG
target:
    @python -c "$$TMP_PYTHON_PROG"
```

First, you're defining a multi line variable with `define` and `endef`.  Then you need to `export` it to the shell otherwise it will treat each new line as a new command.  Then you reinsert the shell variable using `$$`.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your `@<<` thing didn't work is that it appears to be a feature of a non-standard make variant.  Similarly, the `define` command that mVChr mentions is specific (as far as I'm aware) to GNU Make.  While GNU Make is very widely distributed, this trick won't work in a BSD make, nor in a POSIX-only make.

I feel it's good, as a general principle, to keep makefiles as portable as possible; and if you're writing a Makefile in the context of an autoconf-ed system, it's more important still.

A fully portable technique for doing what you're looking for is:

```
target:
    { echo "print 'First line'"; echo "print 'second'"; } | python
```

or equivalently, if you want to lay things out a bit more tidily:

```
target:
    { echo "print 'First line'"; \
      echo "print 'second'"; \
    } | python
```